# Powershell: splitting on multiple characters

Tags: regex, powershell

In Powershell (v2 if it matters), s it possible to split on variable-length strings of a delimiter character?  My input file consists of lines, where each field is separated by one or more tab characters, to keep things in neat columns. There are no leading tabs.  I thought you could use regular expressions in the delimiter specification, so I tried:

```
get-content $INFILE | foreach-object {
    $LINE = $_.split("`t*");
    $F1 = $LINE[0]
    $F2 = $LINE[1]
    $F3 = $LINE[2]
        . . .
}
```

If there is just one tab between each field, it works as required.  If there are two or more, each is treated as a separate delimiter, and some members of $LINE are left empty.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of the `*`? Most regex flavor will match twice `\t` with such an expression: once with `\t` and another with an empty string. Replace it with `+` (that's the behavior you want anyway). (of course, if there are several `\t`, it will first match all of them then an empty string)

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but "`t+" does exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean up the duplicates first and you should be fine.

```
$DedupedLine  = $_ -replace '[\t]+',"`t" # Replace multi tabs with a single tab
$LINE  = $DedupedLine.split('`t')
```

Comment: I assume by $t, you mean $_?

Comment: Yes :)  My test string was amazingly enough, $t.

Answer (score 5):

Try this overload instead. The split method doesn't take a regex pattern, just char(s) or string(s). You could also use multiple assignment and save some lines of code:

```
$f1,$f2,$f3 = $_.Split("`t",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the options using the .NET [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method, the PowerShell [`-split`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113270) operator *does* support regular expressions like `` `t* ``:

```
PS> 'comma,separated,,values' -split ',+'
comma
separated
values
```

To access the first three fields on each line, you could use:

```powershell
$F1,$F2,$F3,$rest = $_ -split "`t+"
```